# How do always display the Numeric keyboard in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm working on windows phone 8 app, I had a page which inputs number for that I gave code like this,

```
<TextBox Name="txtNumber" Height="Auto" Margin="0,10,0,510" >
    <TextBox.InputScope>
        <InputScope>
            <InputScopeName NameValue="Number" />
        </InputScope>
    </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

by the above code; It display the numeric keyboard when I place the cursor to type; But I need a fixed keyboard which is always visible and if we type it has to enter the value to the textbox.

Would somebody please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this on for size:

Xaml:

```
<Grid 
    x:Name="ContentPanel" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Margin="12,0,12,0"
    Loaded="ContentPanel_Loaded">
    <TextBox 
        Name="TB1" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="72" 
        Margin="0,74,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="456"
        InputScope="Number"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Turn on Tab Stops.  You can set this in XAML as well.  
    this.IsTabStop = true;

    // Set focus on the TextBox.
    TB1.Focus();
}
```

It will spark up the SIP as it enters the `<TextBox>` ready for input. Hope it's what your looking for.

Got it from this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/07/02/programmatically-dismiss-the-sip-keyboard-in-windows-phone-silverlight-app.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be with creating your own user control. However it is most likely a lot of work to get it to work as a normal keyboard.
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Silverlight-Custom-Control-The-Basics.aspx

Or maybe perhaps this will help http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx